# Quasar project's pages empty after implementing a Pinia store

Tags: vuejs3, quasar, pinia

I recently implemented a Pinia store in my Quasar peoject, which serves as a central component for all Api calls. Prior to this, I was making an Api call in each of my components which was very inconvenient. However, the issue is now that my pages render nothing but a bizzar default content from Quasar I've never seen before. A screenshot can be seen below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o28QY.png
Besides, the strange thing is that the developer doesn't render anything neigher, not even a 'hello world'!

```
// The stores code:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type { Project, Resource, Task } from './types'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useApiStore = defineStore('types', {
  state: () => ({
    projects: [] as Project[],
    resources: [] as Resource[],
    tasks: [] as Task[],
    loading: false,
    error: null as string | null
  }),

  actions: {
    async fetchData () {
      try {
        const { projects, resources, tasks } = this.$state
        this.$state.loading = true
        const projectsPromise = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/projects')
        const resourcePromise = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/resources')
        const taskPromise = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/tasks')
        const [projectResponse, resourceResponse, taskResponse] = await Promise.all([
          projectsPromise,
          resourcePromise,
          taskPromise
        ])
        const colours: string[] = ['#c1d2e6', '#8b7099', '#f49595', '#f6c094', '#ffebb0', '#a1c698']
        const shuffledColours = colours.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        projects.push(...projectResponse.data)
        resources.push(...resourceResponse.data)
        tasks.push(...taskResponse.data)

        projects.forEach((project, index) => {
          project.duration = new Date(project.endDate).getDate() - new Date(project.startDate).getDate()
          project.colour = shuffledColours[index % shuffledColours.length]
        })
        resources.forEach((resource, index) => {
          resource.colour = shuffledColours[index % shuffledColours.length]
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      } finally {
        this.$state.loading = false
      }
    }
  }
}) 
// A component's code
<template>
  <div>
    <FullCalendar
      :options="options"
      style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); height: 520px; width: 800px;"
    ></FullCalendar>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { EventClickArg, Plugin } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import dropDownButton from './dropDownButton.vue'
import { useApiStore } from '../stores/apiStore'

const store = useApiStore()
const projects = ref(store.projects)

const setProjectDataAsEvents = () => {
  options.events = projects.value.map((project) => ({
    title: project.name,
    extendedProps: { resources: project.resources?.map(resource => `${resource.surname} ${' '} ${resource.lastname}`) },
    start: project.startDate,
    end: project.endDate,
    allDay: true,
    backgroundColor: project.colour,
    textColor: '#000000',
    borderColor: project.colour
  }))
}

const options = {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin] as Plugin[],
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev, today, next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridWeek, dayGridMonth, dayGridYear'
  },
  dropDownButton,
  weekends: true,
  events: [] as { title: string; start: Date; end: Date; allDay: boolean }[],
  eventClick: function (info: EventClickArg) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: info.event.title,
      html: `
        <div>
          <strong>Zeitraum:</strong> <br/>${info.event.start?.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })} - ${info.event.end?.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })}
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>Resourcen:</strong><br>${info.event.extendedProps.resources?.join('<br>')}
        </div>
      `,
      icon: 'info',
      toast: true,
      background: info.event.backgroundColor,
      confirmButtonColor: '#536363',
      iconColor: '#536363',
      showCloseButton: true,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  setProjectDataAsEvents()
})
</script>
´´´
When I hover on the types/variables imported from Pinia store in one of my components the popup window's information indicates that everything is being imported correctly.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Thanks a lot
```

Comment: Pinia is a data store - by definition it has nothing to do with API calls. Also, it is not a `component` but more of a `plugin`. If you want to keep your API calls in a central place - you can combine them in a dedicated ES6 module and export them individually. You don't seem to call `fetchData` - so supposedly your store has an empty list of projects.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The issue was that I wasn't calling the fetchData method, as you said.